# How to iterate a zip list and print each index of it after joining to lists of the same size?

Tags: python

Given the variables:

```
X = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Y = [1, 2, 3]
```

complete the following statement:

```
[print(pair) for pair in ...]
```

so as to print to the screen pairs of elements from X and Y which occupy the same position in the index.

I  know I can make a join `X` and `Y` and make a list using `list(zip(X,Y))` but the adding that in the statement gives an empty list.

I can't solve this problem using the form required any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear what you're trying to achieve. If you need to print pairs, zip works, i.e.

```
for pair in zip(X, Y):
    print(pair)
```

`[print(pair) for pair in ...]` is list comprehension, this is made to create lists, not to print data:

```
pairs_list = [pair for pair in zip(X, Y)]  # don't do this
```

which is simply `pairs_list = list(zip(X, Y))`. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehensions to leverage a sideeffect (like printing something) is frowned upon. If you dont need a list, don't build one.

```
[print(pair) for pair in zip(X,Y)]  # no need to list(zip(...))
```

will result in lots on `None` ... because the return value of `print()` is `None`.

Use a simple loop:

```
for p in zip(X,Y):
    print(p)
```